# using mount(2) function in C

Tags: c, macos, unix

I've have been desperately searching for a tutorial on how to use the mount() function properly (they are very good at hiding this knowledge).

I need to use it to MNT_UPDATE " / "(/dev/disk0s2 in this case) in single user mode but I can't find an example or tutorial on how to use the function.

ps. Please no "Use system()"
pps. I know /sbin/mount exists for a reason, I'm doing this for education purposes

Comment: did you try `man 2 mount`? (or whatever manual category this is in on your local Unix distribution)

Comment: @Nikolai N Fetissov: tags mention OS X.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/mount.2.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/2/mount

Comment: Yes, I understand how to use mount as far as syntactics go I'm just unclear about setting up the arguments I pass to it.

Specifically how one would force MNT_UPDATE on " / " which is initially mounted as read-only in single user mode. essentially I need to do exactly what "/sbin/mount -uw /" does without using "/sbin/mount -uw /"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have probably already read in the man page, you use it like this:

```
int ret = mount("hfs", "/", MNT_UPDATE, some_data);
```

The trick is what goes into "data". It is a filesystem-specific structure that can be found by grepping for the filesystem name in system headers. For example, for HFS it's in `/usr/include/hfs/hfs_mount.h`:

```
struct hfs_mount_args {
    char     *fspec; /* <--- This is the device to mount */
    uid_t     hfs_uid;
    gid_t     hfs_gid;
    mode_t    hfs_mask;
    u_int32_t hfs_encoding;
    struct    timezone hfs_timezone;
    int       flags;
    int       journal_tbuffer_size;
    int       journal_flags;
    int       journal_disable;
};
```

Comment: for fspec would it be hfs_mount_args->fspec = "/dev/disk0s2"?

Comment: <code>
 struct hfs_mount_args some_data; 
 
 
 some_data.fspec = strdup("/dev/disk0s2");
 int res = mount("hfs", "/", MNT_UPDATE ,&some_data);
 
 
 NSLog(@"Error:%d %s",res,strerror(errno));
</code>
gives me Error:0 No such file or directory

Comment: @edlundquist: it's not exactly a forum :) Anyways, code should be surrounded by backticks, \`like this\`, which does `like this`. For the error code, a return value of `0` from `mount` indicates success, so maybe it did work and `errno` was set by something else previously.

Comment: @edlundquist, you have a success return code (and errno is undefined in this case, so it should be ignored). What happens to your mount point?

Comment: It gains read right privileges which is what I wanted, but now it seems like the only partition I can mount is disk0s2, attempting to mount disk0s3 returns an -1 if attempt to mount it at /Volumes/testpartition

Comment: @edlundquist what's in errno in the second case?

Comment: returns -1 errno is Invalid Address

Comment: @edlundquist man page states that errno is set to EFAULT if you pass an invalid pointer for your dir argument.

Comment: the directory testpartition exists i'm not sure why it wouldn't mount it

Comment: @edlundquist, I meant pointer pointing to invalid memory, rather than anything to do with a directory itself. I'd appreciate a code sample.

Comment: @edlundquist You don't seem to initialise other members of `struct hfs_mount_args`, so they may contain garbage.

Comment: I went through and initialized everything in the struct and it still fails to mount, I get -1 Invalid Argument

Comment: So I'm trying to figure out what the args would be for an nfs mount. there's no nfs header. There is, in sysproto.h struct nfsclnt_args, but it doesn't quite look like it. Any ideas?

Comment: I tried dtrussing through the mount_nfs call, but whereas strace shows you params, dtruss only seems to show pointer values.

Comment: Hi, I'm dealing with a similar issue, except that i wish to mount directly from a regular file and not device file (under `/dev/`). perhaps do you know if i can use other image format besides the propriety `dmg` which can be used in `mount(2)` command to mount the image file directly to mountpoint ? (notice that if I use dmg file, the only way to mount it directly is using the shell command `hdiutil attach` and i wish to do it programmatically)

Comment: I want to mount a fat32 device, but there is no directory named vfat in `/usr/include`, only `hfs` and `vfs` on mac. Is possible to mount fat32 with system call `mount`, and how to configure `data` parameter?  `mount(2)`  manual say little about `data`.